# How to deal with lindex and backslashes in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I have a bunch of data I am parsing through Tcl but running into issues when using `lindex` on the strings since it contains backslashes.

For example,

```
$data is a list split by lines, 
{123 somethinghere/somethingthere/\idontcare 123ff}
{456 apples/oranges/\bananas 921} 
{999 pikachu/ratata/\snorlax ftp}
```

I loop on `$data` and use `lindex` to split this data and group it according to its type:

```
foreach item $data {
    set num [lindex $item 0]
    set paths [lindex $item 1]
    set output [lindex $item 2]
}
```

Unfortunately, the backslashes escape the text I want.

```
puts "$paths"
somethinghere/somethingthere/dontcare
```

Ideally I don't even want to preserve the backslashes. My preferred data on `$path` would be:

```
puts "$paths"
somethinghere/somethingthere/idontcare
```

Suggestions? I don't want to use regexp unless that's the only way.

Comment: Where do the backslashes come from? Do they mean anything in the data?

Comment: It's spelled 'rattata', by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First rule of lists is: **don't treat non-list things as lists** (well, there are exceptions to this but your data is a good example why you should follow the rule in 99% of cases).

To convert the string properly to a list use `split`:

```
set i [split $item " "]
```

If the split character is variable or is more than one char use `regexp`:

```
set i [regexp -inline -all {\S+} $item]
```

By using commands that return lists you are guaranteed that you get a proper list. Unless you're 100% sure (the exception) strings are not always parseable as lists.

---

Now, as for how to get rid of `\`. You can of course use regexp for this:

```
set item [regsub -all {\\} $item]
```

But there's a better way to do this without using regexp (which I'm sure you'd appreciate), use `string map`:

```
set item [string map {"\\" ""} $item]
```